# Parse error in var_dump

Tags: php

I am getting parse error in following code:

```
<?php
// This:
$a = array( 'color' => 'red',
            'taste' => 'sweet',
            'shape' => 'round',
            'name'  => 'apple',
            4        // key will be 0
          );

$b = array('a', 'b', 'c');

// . . .is completely equivalent with this:
$a = array();
$a['color'] = 'red';
$a['taste'] = 'sweet';
$a['shape'] = 'round';
$a['name']  = 'apple';
$a[]        = 4;        // key will be 0

$b = array();
$b[] = 'a';
$b[] = 'b';
$b[] = 'c';

// After the above code is executed, $a will be the array
// array('color' => 'red', 'taste' => 'sweet', 'shape' => 'round', 
// 'name' => 'apple', 0 => 4), and $b will be the array 
// array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c'), or simply array('a', 'b', 'c')

var_dump($a);
echo <br>
var_dump($b);
echo <br>
?>
```

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/ashish/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject1/index.php on line 31

What is wrong in above code?

---

Ok the correct way to put breaks is this.

```
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Please learn some basic PHP before attempting to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't output HTML directly inside of PHP tags. Use `echo` instead:

```
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: OK but the still it's not parsing

Comment: @AshishYadav: It's not. Try it and see.

Comment: Wait 5 minutes and I will accept this as answer, as required by forum.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix freely HTML and PHP (unless you are not using [XHP](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/xhp-a-new-way-to-write-php/294003943919)), you have to close the php or use echo

```
var_dump($a);?>
<br>
<?php var_dump($b);?>
<br>
```

Comment: OK but the still it's not parsing

Comment: Line 31 is the echo statement